# How to make an index for a dimension dependent on indices for other dimensions in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3D numpy array (`A`) and I would like to make a 2D array (`B`) out of it using the following algorithm.

For every index along the first and second dimension I have a value of the index for the third dimension. This mapping can be represented as a 2D array. For example:

```
Z = array([
       [3, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [3, 0, 2],
       [2, 2, 3]
       ])
```

This means, for example, that

```
B[0,0] = A[0, 0, Z[0, 0]] = A[0, 0, 3]
B[0,1] = A[0, 1, Z[0, 1]] = A[0, 0, 1]
...
B[i,j] = A[i, j, Z[i, j]]
```

What would be an elegant and fast way to do it in numpy?

Answer (score 0):

I would do smth like:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(60).reshape(3, 4, 5)
Z = np.random.randint(0, A.shape[-1], size = A.shape[:-1])
B = np.empty(A.shape[:-1])

idx0 = np.arange(A.shape[0]).repeat(A.shape[1])
idx1 = np.arange(A.shape[1]).reshape(1, -1).repeat(A.shape[0], axis = 0).flatten()
idx2 = Z[idx0, idx1]
B[idx0, idx1] = A[idx0, idx1, idx2]
```

output:

```
A = 
[[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
  [ 5  6  7  8  9]
  [10 11 12 13 14]
  [15 16 17 18 19]]

 [[20 21 22 23 24]
  [25 26 27 28 29]
  [30 31 32 33 34]
  [35 36 37 38 39]]

 [[40 41 42 43 44]
  [45 46 47 48 49]
  [50 51 52 53 54]
  [55 56 57 58 59]]]
Z = 
[[2 3 2 3]
 [3 3 2 1]
 [1 0 1 4]]
B = 
[[ 2.  8. 12. 18.]
 [23. 28. 32. 36.]
 [41. 45. 51. 59.]]
```

You can also do the following, which is basically the same, but uses less lines of code.

```
A = np.arange(60).reshape(3, 4, 5)
Z = np.random.randint(0, A.shape[-1], size = A.shape[:-1])

idx0, idx1 = np.mgrid[:A.shape[0], :A.shape[1]]
B = A[idx0, idx1, Z[idx0, idx1]]
```